# Why does pressing ctrl+space bring up a keyboard layout menu?

Tags: xorg, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

I am trying out StumpWM, however when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> I get a menu to change keyboard layouts. This conflicts with emacs region selection. What causes this behaiviour and how do I disable it?

I have inspected stumpwm's *top-map* keymap and it appears to not be a StumpWM binding. And looking into man xkeyboard-config I can't see such a binding there.

<sub>(Sidenote: I am using xkbcomp to load keyboard layout I want on StumpWM's rc.)</sub>

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/emacs24/+bug/1296790 I have found the what, but still looking for the how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I found it was [ibus that was causing the conflict](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/emacs24/+bug/1296790), and the way to disable it is to run (sudo) `ibus-setup` and disable the keybinding